# How do you find what GroupPolicy objects are attached to a container/domain/site?

Tags: c++, active-directory, ldap, group-policy

I've got a problem where I need to interleave settings made on the host/user/containers/domain/site with the group policy settings attached to the containers/domain/site.

We can walk the ad tree for the host and the user and have those settings.
We have our group policy list & objects and those settings.
I'm just having trouble joining the 2 heirarchies back together, I can't seem to find the appripriate API/info to do it.

Comment: I am not quite sure I understand your question.  Did you say that you already got a list of GPOs but you want to get the resultant set of policy?  You can use [RSoP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa375082%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) library to get the GPO as well as the resultant policy.  This is how Microsoft generates the GP reports

Comment: Back before GPO was in our app worked by extending the schema and storing some settings directly on the user/container objects.  Later when people found that the org structure didn't match the way they wanted to apply settings for our app similar settings where stored in GPO.  The problem is when people use the settings in both container and GPO which order to take them in and joining them together.  At the moment we simply do container then gpo which is not what the users expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to look at the `gpLink` attribute of each site, domain, and OU. You can also look at `gpOptions` for a handful of related flags. The `gpLink` attribute will have the DNs of each GPO applied to that object as well as whether or not the link is enabled or not.